# how to find community-wiki content associated with stackoverflow topics

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

Stackoverflow is said to have wiki as an intergral part. Where can I find the contents of it

Can you point me any URL of the same?

Also if i would like to post some article on wiki how do I post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole site is somewhat wiki. If you have enough reputation (>= 2000), you can edit other peoples posts. (Reputation still goes to the OP.)

Community wiki questions are questions that either are discussions, have more than 30 (15 on SU) answers, or have been edited too much.

The difference to other questions and answers is that nobody will gain reputation with them and therefore some things are allowed that will not be allowed in normal questions, like polling or open ended questions, and if you are lucky and have enough people interested even off topic questions.

When you ask a question or write an answer, there is a check box at the lower right corner of the edit box to turn your question into a cw post.

You can [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) for community wiki questions using

```
wiki:1 oranges apples
```

One needs at least 100 rep to edit cw posts.

There is another wiki aspect: you can help describe a tag. Click on any tag and then change to the info tag.

Tag wikis contain frequently asked questions and guidelines about using the tag. They help introduce newcomers to the tag.

The top 20 answerers and any users with more than 100 upvotes on answers for the tag are allowed to edit it. As long as they have more than 2000 reputation points.

Comment: An added note - if you want to specifically find community wiki questions, add "views:0" to your search query. Only questions can have views.